# ie6 text wrapping issue

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-6

My tool tip text doesn't wrap with given text in ie6,
live example http://jsfiddle.net/hWAJh/

All other browsers text is wrapped, but in IE6 doesn't, used code as follows.

HTML code

```
<div id="CountryDiv" class="toolTipHolder">  
    <p>
        <img src="question-mark.png" alt=""/>
        <span>Best tooltip goes here for user information, can you feel this?</span>   
    </p>
</div>
```

CSS code

```
div.toolTipHolder {
    position:relative;
    z-index:24; 
}

div.toolTipHolder p{ 
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    top:0; 
    left:0; 
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    background-color:#FFF; 
    border:blue 1px solid;
    color:#000;
    text-align: left;
    font-size:11px;
    padding:5px;
}

div.toolTipHolder p span {
    padding-left:5px;
    width:150px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    border:red 1px solid;
}
```

Comment: Checking it with http://ipinfo.info/netrenderer/ (because I can't be bothered booting my virtual machine), it appears to wrap: http://i.stack.imgur.com/2i3wd.png

Comment: What @thirtydot said, wraps for me too...

Comment: I'm wondering, for me, its not working in IE6 :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changed as follows, it works for me.

```
div.tooltipText {
    margin-left:5px;
    width:80%;
    height:140px;
    font-size:11px;
    white-space: pre-wrap;       /* css-3 */
    white-space: -moz-pre-wrap !important;  /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
    white-space: -pre-wrap;      /* Opera 4-6 */
    white-space: -o-pre-wrap;    /* Opera 7 */
    white-space : normal      /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding,

```
white-space:nowrap
```

Worked for me for IE6.